# How to include two text boxes texts?

Tags: c#

I want to include two text box texts to one text box like this
both of them are multiline.
But I want special form of include, in other words I want to include them like this

```
textbox 1 texts: '' help''' '' other''  
textbox 2 texts:' 1'     '2'   '' 3''  
results: help1 _  help2  _ help3  
other1_other2_other3
```

Comment: So you want to add multiple strings to the same textbox? You can do that by simply using the + operator in between the strings. So textbox1.text = "help " + "other";.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the uaer put 2 words in text box 1 and put 5 words in text box 2 i give you an example

Comment: text box 1 include this words: hello     bye  <br> and text box 2  1234  4567  789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiline textboxes return a string array with the lines in the `Lines` property. You could do something like this

```
string[] words = textBox1.Lines;
string[] numbers = textBox2.Lines;
var resultLines = new string[words.Length];
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++) {
    sb.Length = 0; // Reset StringBuilder for the next line.
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.Length; j++) {
        sb.Append(words[i]).Append("-").Append(numbers[j]).Append("_");
    }
    if (sb.Length > 0) {
        sb.Length--; // remove the last "_"
    }
    resultLines[i] = sb.ToString();
}
resultsTextBox.Lines = resultLines;
```

First we get the `words` and `numbers` arrays. Then we create a new array for the result. Since we want a result line for each word, we make it `words.Length` in size.

Then we loop through the words. We use a `StringBuilder` to build our new lines. This is more efficient as concatenation strings with `+`, as it minimizes copy operations and memory allocations.

In a nested loop we put the words and numbers together.

Comment: Thank you its working but I want "-" between texts of text box 1 and text box like this hello-@123

Comment: Well, then just replace `"_"` by `"-"` Like this: `sb.Append(words[i]).Append(numbers[j]).Append("-");`. You show underlines in your question.

Comment: its put "_" between two lines but I want to put them between two words like this< textBox1 = "hello" textbox2 = "123"   result: hello-123

Comment: Look more closely at the code to understand what it does. `sb.Append(words[i]).Append("-").Append(numbers[j]);`. It's as simple as moving the `.Append("-")` between words and numbers. You should also take more care to give us an exact description of what you want in the question. The examples you give are not very precise.

Comment: if I want to do this from the txt file what I have to do (user chose txt file)

Comment: Have a look at [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netframework-4.8). There are a lot of static `Read...` methods there.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to solve your issue is to make use of the `String.Join` method in C#. I'm adding this answer because I'm a big fan of the method and think it must be part of some answer to this question because it has to do with combining strings. 
Here's the code that I'd use to solve the challenge:

```cs
string[] firstInput = textBox1.Lines;
string[] secondInput = textBox2.Lines;
var combinedInputs = new string[firstInput.Length];
var combinedLine = new string[secondInput.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < firstInput.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < secondInput.Length; j++)
    {
        combinedLine[j] = firstInput[i] + secondInput[j];
    }
    //Combine all values of combinedLine with a '-' in between and add this to combinedInputs.
    combinedInputs[i] = String.Join("-", combinedLine);
}
outputTextBox.Lines = combinedInputs; //the resulting output
```

I hope this answer helped aswell. And I'd like to give credits to Olivier for explaining the textbox part. Another thing that I'd like to add is that this answer isn't meant to be the most efficient, but is meant to be easy to read and understand.

Comment: if I want to do this from the txt file what I have to do (user chose txt file)

Comment: I'd start by googling: How to read from a txt file in C#. The path that is submitted can be used to find the txt file.